# Eclipse Own welcome page through Plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have added a menu name "Abhishek Welcome Page".

> Till now I have added the content in a
>   view and displayed it as full screen

.

But now I want to develop my welcome page as eclipse does. I tried to use the intro package but I could not get the actual way to do that, I mean what is product and how to make it done. I tried with RCP and it worked very easily but stuck with eclipse help screen through Plug-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Creating product branding](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/product-guide/guide.html) article. It also contains a section on the Welcome-screen. A more recent article is also [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#product). If something doesn't work, please tell us what exactly you tried (incl. code and any error messages). Good luck!

Comment: Can you suggest me any solution for the problem I am facing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509679/how-to-provide-a-custom-component-in-the-existing-web-page-editor-palette