# eclipse Platform.getOS/getV throwing exception

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse Platform.getOS is throwing null Pointer Exception.
Even any kind of operation with Platform is throing exception.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getOS(InternalPlatform.java:454)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getOS(Platform.java:1185)
>     at Test.main(Test.java:6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running your classes on top of OSGi or just accessing the Platform class within a plain java application?

Comment: I created a Plug-in project and there I am writing a normal java class with main

Comment: Platform is the central piece of Eclipse Runtime. And Eclipse Runtime is an OSGi library. So you can't expect that to work fine without an OSGi instance. You should run the plugin as an Eclipse Application not as a Java Application

Comment: Can you suggest me any solution for the problem I am facing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509679/how-to-provide-a-custom-component-in-the-existing-web-page-editor-palette